# Ubuntu + SVN + Apache2

Tags: svn, ubuntu, apache2, lamp

I am working on a new project, and for that i need to install a SVN server. This is done right now.

At the moment i've running:
- Ubuntu
- Apache
- PHP5/MySQL
- A svn server

I can call the SVN server at http:// 192.168.1.36/svn/*projectname* with ToirtoiseSVN, when check out i get all the files right.

But I cann't visit that project right now, the domain is www.projectname.lan (Changed the hosts-file in Windows to 192.168.1.36) and installed a Vhost to var/www/*projectname* and that's working.

The only problem I have is when I commit files to the SVN it doesn't update var/www/*projectname* but it update /home/svn/*projectname*.

So the problem is that I Can't visit my new commits and stuff. Is there a possibility to let me visit http://www.projectname.lan and visit the last revision?

Thanks a lot for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your checkout points to the old repository path. You need to checkout with the new URL.

Comment: If the URL of the repository changed you don't need to do a new checkout. `svn switch` is the command to fix such an issue.

Comment: You are correct, of course. I didn't mention this on purpose (start with a clean checkout etc.).

Comment: When i try this i get "svn: '/var/www/project' is not a working copy